# Switching from jQuery autocomplete to Twitter Typeahead

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js

I have some code that uses the autocomplete jquery plugin, with the source as a json file that is generated dynamically.

```
funderInput.autocomplete({
    //Look up funders by name and show suggestions
    source:function(request, response) {
        $.getJSON("/funder/suggest?name=" + request.term, function(data){
            response($.map(data.result.suggestions, function(item, index) {
                return {label: item.name + " (" + item.location + ")", value: item.fundref};
            }))
        })
    }
});
```

I can't work out how to do something similar in Typeahead.
The examples in the documentation suggest the following, but seem use a static JSON file.

```
var bestPictures = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  prefetch: '../data/films/post_1960.json',
  remote: '../data/films/queries/%QUERY.json'
});

bestPictures.initialize();

$('#remote .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'best-pictures',
  displayKey: 'value',
  source: bestPictures.ttAdapter()
});
```

I tried this, but not really getting far!

```
defaults.typeahead.typeahead({
    // Options
    minLength: 1,
    highlight: true,
}, {
    // Dataset
    source: function (query, process) {
        $.getJSON("/funder/suggest?name=" + query, function (data) {
            response($.map(data.result.suggestions, function (item, index) {
                return {
                    label: item.name + " (" + item.location + ")",
                    value: item.fundref
                };
            }))
        });
    }
});
```

I'm a JavaScript novice so a gentle kick in the right direction is what I'm after if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in typeahead function is called process instead of response. Try with returning process

```
source: function (query, process) {
        $.getJSON("/funder/suggest?name=" + query, function (data) {
           return  process($.map(data.result.suggestions, function (item, index) {
                return {
                    label: item.name + " (" + item.location + ")",
                    value: item.fundref
                };
            }))
        });
    }
```

Comment: Do you know whether Typeahead has equivalents for label and value?

Comment: You can make your own. Refer here: http://tatiyants.com/how-to-use-json-objects-with-twitter-bootstrap-typeahead/

Comment: Are you referring to this: `map[state.stateName] = state;`?

Comment: Yes that part. Look there how var map ={} is created and then an array is passed to process function. in map actual object is stored and states array (in that example) will contain list of string which will displayed.

Comment: I'm totally lost on this.  I don't have a list of mutliple states (like in the example, so don't need the `$.each` and I can't work out how to do it without this.

Comment: Can you please make a clear question (may be a new) what you want to achieve? Do you want display custom text or value? Where are you  stuck? As far as I understood, you want to have label/value thing changed so those are the possibilities.

Comment: Yeah I realised I was deviating away from my original question so sorry about that.  I'll come up with a new question to make it clearer.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: New question here, if you fancy having a crack at it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26164337/mapping-in-twitter-typeahead-with-remote-json-file